# qual o erro deste codigo

Tags: python

```
class Point3D(object):
    def _init_(self,x,y,z):
     a=str(x) 
     self.x=a
     a=str
     self.y=a
     a=a+","
     a=str(z)
     self.z=a
    def _repr_(self):
        return "(%d,%d,%d)"%(self.x,self.y,self.z)

my_point=Point3D(1,2,3)
print(my_point)
```

Comment: Olá, Emanuel. Seja bem-vindo. Sua pergunta está muito confusa. É difícil dizermos qual é o erro sem sabermos o que você está querendo fazer e o que está acontecendo em vez disso. Se há alguma saída de erro do compilador/interpretador, também é importante que coloque. Se ainda não o fez, que tal fazer um [tour] do site para entender melhor como funciona? Depois, volte e edite a sua pergunta clicando no link "Editar".

Answer (score 2):

Estude o coemntário feito, e tente melhorar a questão - mas olhando o código, mesmo sem saber a mensagem que você vê, uma coisa errada é que o método `_init_` deveria ser  `__init__` (com dois underscores o prefixo e no sufixo) - para ter o efeito que provavelmente você pretende: isso é, que ele seja chamado automaticamente pela linguagem quando a classe `Point3D` for instanciada.

É uma convenção da linguagem, todos os métodos que serão chamados por mecanismos internos da linguagem estão cercados por dois sublinahdos `__` de cada lado.